# Color changeable SVG?

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

I wish to build a website where icon colors can be easily changed with the only change of the css. I've been given a set of custom icons in form of svg files.

I've already experimented with background color, filters and alike (see https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-montalcini-xfufu?file=/index.html).

Which is the best technique to use? Should I generate a font from the SVGs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, open your SVG file and change the style of the `.cls-1` path:

```
.cls-1 { fill: currentColor; }
```

Now place the SVG inside your HTML code. The color of the shield will follow the current font color. The `<use>` tag will allow you to duplicate it easily. Just make sure to hide the original instance of the SVG with `style="display: none;"`.

```css
svg {
  width: 42px;
  height: 50px;
}

.green-icon { color: green; }
.red-icon { color: red; }
.blue-icon { color: blue; }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 768.42 907.1" style="display: none;"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:currentColor;}.cls-2{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><g id="Livello_2" data-name="Livello 2"><g id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1"><path class="cls-1" d="M766.27,141.2c-157.6,0-279.1-44.3-382.5-141.2C282,97.7,160.47,141.2,2.07,141.2c0,253.7-53.4,618.2,382.5,765.9C820.47,758.6,766.27,394.9,766.27,141.2Z"/><path class="cls-2" d="M449.87,436.6a43.42,43.42,0,0,1,28.9-7.1l113.9-114-63.8-63.8L415,365.7a42.67,42.67,0,0,1-7.4,29.2Z"/><polygon class="cls-2" points="251.17 575.4 246.97 571.3 225.37 588.8 188.97 646.1 198.37 655.4 255.67 619 273.17 597.5 268.97 593.3 341.47 520.8 323.47 503.1 251.17 575.4"/><path class="cls-2" d="M350.27,374.5a88.86,88.86,0,0,0-108.9-109.8l50.4,50.3-13.2,49.3-49.4,13.2-50.3-50.3a88.86,88.86,0,0,0,113.5,107.7l.3.3,207.1,207.1a42,42,0,0,0,59.4-59.4Zm182.8,261a16,16,0,1,1,16.1-16A16,16,0,0,1,533.07,635.5Z"/></g></g></svg>

<svg class="green-icon" viewBox="0 0 768.42 907.1"><use href="#Layer_1"></use></svg>
<svg class="red-icon" viewBox="0 0 768.42 907.1"><use href="#Layer_1"></use></svg>
<svg class="blue-icon" viewBox="0 0 768.42 907.1"><use href="#Layer_1"></use></svg>
```

(This solution is based on [this article](https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/) from CSS Tricks.)

Answer (score -1):

Generating a custom icon font would property be the best idea, since you have the fastest implementation in your HTML markup and don't have to care about embedding images again an again anymore.

https://icomoon.io is a great generator when you are looking for a helper software to generate your font.